# C++ Linux Sockets adding variable in char *msg

Tags: c++, linux, string, sockets, char

I'm trying to add a insert a variable to a send().

here is the code:

```
string num;

// + num + is the reason for the error. Any work around or suggestions?
char *msg = "GET /index.php?num=" + num + " HTTP/1.1\nhost: domain.com\n\n";

int len;
ssize_t bytes_sent;
len = strlen(msg);
bytes_sent = send(socketfd, msg, len, 0);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
test.cpp: In function âint main()â:
test.cpp:64: error: cannot convert âstd::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >â to âchar*â in initialization
```

--edit--

I tried to fix it with msg.c_str

```
cout << "send()ing message..."  << endl;
string msg = "GET /index.php?num=" + num + " HTTP/1.1\nhost: domain.com\n\n";   
int len;
ssize_t bytes_sent;
len = msg.lenght(); //updated to this and still gives me an error.
bytes_sent = send(socketfd, msg.c_str, len, 0);
```

Now it gives me the error:

```
error: argument of type âconst char* (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >::)()constâ does not match âconst char*â
```

Comment: There's a reason they made a string class and don't use char pointers and arrays directly anymore  -- which is, stuff like `chars + string + chars` doesn't do the right thing.  :P

Comment: @edit, use string::length. len = msg.lenght();

Comment: error: âstruct std::stringâ has no member named âlenghtâ

Comment: If you want to use strlen: 
const char *cstr = msg.c_str();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"stuff" + num + "more stuff"` doesn't do what you'd expect.  Even if you were to convert `str` to a char pointer, and even if C++ let you add char pointers together, it'd end up doing the totally wrong thing.

(For reference, C++ *doesn't* let you add pointers together, because the result doesn't make any sense.  Pointers are still just numbers, and adding two char pointers would basically amount to `0x59452448 + 0x10222250` or something like that, which would return you a pointer to some location that probably doesn't even exist yet...)

Try this:

```
string msg = string("GET /index.php?num=") + num + " HTTP/1.1\nhost: domain.com\n\n";
ssize_t bytes_sent = send(socketfd, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0);
```

Comment: Hello, tried it. Got an error  invalid conversion from âconst char*â to âchar*â

Answer (score 1):

You're using `num` where it is uninitialized on the third line. Maybe you want:

```
std::string num;
std::string msg = "GET /index.php?num=" + num + " HTTP/1.1\nhost: domain.com\n\n";
```

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to do that? Inserting the variable between? I mean an alternative? I guess thats whats making the error.

Comment: Why are you doing `char + string + char` in the first place?

Comment: I tried changing num into a char. but i get an error. error: invalid operands of types âconst char*â and âconst char [70]â to binary âoperator+â

Comment: @user1553142 Use `std::string` for all your string handling. It eliminates problems like these.

Comment: I tried it, and still got an error.  error: cannot convert âstd::stringâ to âconst void*â for argument â2â to âssize_t send(int, const void*, size_t, int)â

Comment: Is the `send` function yours or is it supplied for you?

Comment: @user1553142 Why are you passing a string anyway? The function isn't expecting a string but rather a `const void *` type.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not implicitly converted to `char*`. You need to use `c_str`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should work entirely with strings (not char*) in your application, right up to the point where an API function requires a char*, and at that point you call `c_str` on the string to get a const char* for the function you're calling.